# Access string property of object stored in mxArray

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I like using `mexEvalString` cause its easy to execute within mex. However, I get exceptions for some commands so I want to catch them to see what happend using `mexEvalStringWithTrap`, but I fail to get the string from the exception.

Basically it's just getting a string from an object, so I found `mxGetProperty` and `mxGetString` but still this code does not work. Output is `identifier: (null)`

`mxGetN` returns `37` but there seems to be a problem with `str` (maybe flawed usage of `mxGetString`)

```
/* ENTRY POINT */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{    
    mxArray *except, *char_ident;
    mwSize strlen;
    char *str;

/* ARGUMENT VERIFICATION */
    //...
    // catch exception
    except = mexEvalStringWithTrap("unknownfunction");
    // get exception identifier
    char_ident = mxGetProperty(except, 0, "identifier");
    // get identifier string length
    strlen = (mwSize)mxGetN(char_ident);
    // get identifier string
    mxGetString(char_ident, str, strlen+1);
    // print identifier string
    printf("identifier: %s\n", str);
    mexEvalStringWithTrap("drawnow");
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate `str` before you call `mxGetString` (although it may be easier to use `mxArrayToString` instead, see bottom).

**testMEXException.cpp**

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mxArray *except, *char_ident;
    mwSize strlen;
    char *str;

    // catch exception
    except = mexEvalStringWithTrap("unknownfunction");

    // get identifier string
    char_ident = mxGetProperty(except, 0, "identifier");
    strlen = (mwSize)mxGetN(char_ident);
    size_t buflen = strlen*sizeof(mxChar) + 1;
    str = (char*)mxMalloc(buflen);                  //  ALLOCATE
    mxGetString(char_ident, str, strlen + 1);

    // print identifier string
    printf("identifier: %s\n", str);
    mexEvalStringWithTrap("drawnow");

    // get message string
    char_ident = mxGetProperty(except, 0, "message");
    strlen = (mwSize)mxGetN(char_ident);
    buflen = strlen*sizeof(mxChar) + 1;
    str = (char*)mxRealloc(str, buflen);            //  REALLOCATE
    mxGetString(char_ident, str, strlen + 1);

    // print message string
    printf("message: %s\n", str);
    mexEvalStringWithTrap("drawnow");

    mxFree(str);                                    //  FREE
}
```

**Output**

```
>> testMEXException
identifier: MATLAB:UndefinedFunction
message: Undefined function or variable 'unknownfunction'.
```

Alternatively, use `mxArrayToString`, which allocates the buffer internally with enough space for the whole string contained in the input `mxArray`, but which still requires you to free it:

```
str = mxArrayToString(char_ident);
// use str ...
mxFree(str);
```

Your code to capture the `MException` object and to access the `identifier` property are fine.